# rails tutorial, feed with all users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, feed, twitter-feed

I'm doing the rails tutorial and in it we make a feed like twitter with your own posts and following others. I wanted to know how I could take this feed an include all posts on the home page and only the specific user's on their page. Right now I can see my own tweets and those I'm following on the home page and then the same on my profile page. I want my profile page to stay the same with only my own posts but I want the home page to render all posts from all users.

My home page code is like so

`<td class="micropost">
    <span class="user">
        <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
    </span>
    <span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
        Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
  </td>
  <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>`

My Micropost Controller:

```
'before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:create, :destroy]
```

before_filter :authorized_user, :only => :destroy

def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end'

my Pages controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
```

def home
    @title = "Home"
    if signed_in?
      @micropost = Micropost.new
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    end
  end

if somebody could help me or point me in the right direction that would be great. I'm sorry if I asked this question the wrong away or in the wrong format I'm a noob at this and looking it up online hasn't really helped me and I was recommended stackoverflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the beginning of the block of code in your view? Something that looks like:

<% users.feed each do |user| %>

Also, what is the code like on your profile page?

Comment: https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app   is the exact code I have on my application. I thought that would make it a little easier. Thanks

Comment: I was able to get it to do what I wanted by getting rid of the from_users_follow_by(self) part of the def feed micropost. in my user.rb but if there is another way to do it, or do it more efficiently I'd still like to know. Thanks